# Proof that $\int f(x-a)\cdot g(x)dx = \int f(x)\cdot g(x+a) dx$

Tags: integration

How can one proof that:

\begin{equation}
\int f(x-a)\cdot g(x)dx = \int f(x)\cdot g(x+a) dx
\end{equation}

and on what boundaries would this hold (I assume only $[-\infty, \infty]$)?

Comment: In general you will have $\int f(x)dx = \int f(-a)dx$. Show true for characteristic functions, simple functions and then integrable functions.

Comment: $u$-substitution?

Comment: @copper.hat Did you mean in general $\int f(x)dx=\int f(x-a) dx$?

Comment: @TomKern I think that's it actually. By using u subtitution you get the right hand side of the equation. Although, I dont know what will happen to the boundaries since the equation is ofcourse not valid for all boundaries.

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, the Lebesque measure is translation invariant.

Comment: @coffeemath I just noticed now why you made that comment. I did not realise there was a missing $x$.